# Why tcp/ip model is being used for Developing Protocols and not OSI

Tags: tcp, tcpip

why TCP/IP model is used for designing Protocols and why not OSI model,if i am not wrong OSI is the first reference model and in TCP/IP model same concept is followed but coupled with other  layers.

Is there any reason developers dropped OSI and following TCP/Ip even with same concepts.

Comment: TCP/IP model came first, it is at least 10 years older than the OSI model.

Comment: I like those non constructive questions. It makes you _think_. I am comparing to those like "my DNS returns HTTP/404" type, which are actually "destructive" questions.

Answer (score 3):

After I googled your question I came up with the following conclusion:

TCP/IP works better in practice while OSI works better in theory in regards to implementation. Also because TCP/IP and OSI seemed to be a bit incompatible and there already was a TCP/IP protocol based on the model, people just kept going with TCP/IP.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main difference between TCP/IP and OSI model is that one is protocol-specific and one is as-generic-as-can-be.

The question is not TCP/IP or OSI as they are not incompatible. TCP is a layer-4 protocol in the OSI model and IP is a layer-3 protocol in the OSI model. But there are many other protocols that can be adapted in these layers. For example IPX, IGMP and ICMP are other layer-3 protocols and UDP is another layer-4 protocol.

Also the OSI models covers more as it includes lower layers which are very important to the networking world. One problem with the OSI layer is that it is a little bit too "extensive" as layers 5 through 7 are often merged into one.

Not contradictory. Just different.